# retrieve keystore password from appcelerator studio

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, keystore

Due to an accident I lost my keystore password - but I still can distribute it to google play store, because it is still stored somewhere in appcelerators config files.

When I publish it, the alias password is visible in the log, not masked... but unfortunately the keystore password is masked.

Is there a way to retrieve the keystore password from studio?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in luck. Because Appcelerator indeed stores the keystore information you can retrieve it. Not in Studio though, but the password is saved in the `.settings` folder inside your project folder. The `.settings` folder is a hidden folder.

To be exact, you can find it in this file:

`/myProjectDirectory/.settings/com.appcelerator.titanium.android.core.prefs`